# .Net Emit - Add Try Catch block to existing method in runtime

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, reflection.emit, ilgenerator

I use the PubSub mechanism the send events in my application,
each event has a custom handler that use to handle it.

My problem is that in many places the handler suppled as the following:

```
SubscriberService.Subscribe(new SubscribeRequest<string>
{  
   Topic = TopicName,
   Action = async pubSubEvent => await DoSomthingAsync()
}
```

the return type of Action is void so behind the scenes this lambda translated to async void.

So when an exception occur I have no chance to catch it.

I wondered to myself if there is a way to create a method at runtime that warp the method body of the action with a try-catch block that catches the exception when they occur and write them to the log.

I saw some articles about the Emit.IlGenerator class could help but I have no idea where to start.

I would love to hear any suggestions to deal with these issues.

Thanks!

Comment: The code in DoSomething needs to use a THROW so the error can be seen by high level modules.  Once an exception is handle by a method, parent code will not detect the error unless THROW is used.

Comment: @Thanks for your comment @jdweng
But its not the case that I mentioned because
even if we define `DoSomthing = () => {Throw new Exception; }`
and the handler will handle it as the following:

`void MsgEvent(object sender, EncodedMessageEventArgs eArgs)
{
   try
      {
          request.Action((PubSubEvent<T>)eArgs.ReceivedObject)
       }
       catch(exception e){log(e);}
}`
The catch block will not catch the exception, and the exception will be thrown to the synchronization context.

Comment: You cannot put the throw in the parent. It must be in the try block where the exception was first caught. If the exception is in a library you are out of luck unless you can modify the source code.  There is no TRY in child than the parent will capture the exception. c# when an exception occurs the compiled code moves up the execution stack and locates the first exception handler. The exception handler doesn't have to be inside the block of code that executed. For example if there is a IF/ELSE and the if call a method that gets an exception.  A TRY/CATCH in the else may capture the exception.